# ADA accessibility error empty heading using variable

Tags: html, accessibility, visualforce

I am currently trying to make a Visualforce page ADA compliant and I am getting an empty heading error when using a handlebar variable for a validation message

```
<h4>{!theApp.Application_Stage__r.Stage__r.Application_Custom_Message__c}</h4>
```

how do I fix this issue?

Comment: Don't use a heading?

Comment: If there is no error, does the `h4` render empty?

Comment: As long as the variable always produces an output, it won't matter. You can safely ignore the error that your tool is producing. Otherwise, if there are situations where the variable may not render, then you may need to place a conditional `if` block around the entire h4 so that it only displays when there will be value assigned.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by adding a custom class to the element

```
<h4 class="hiddenValidate"></h4>
```

and then using the jQuery .remove() method

```
 $('.hiddenValidate:empty').parent().remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hiding via JavaScript is one way, may I suggest an even better way, CSS.

```
h1:empty,
h2:empty,
h3:empty,
h4:empty,
h5:empty,
h6:empty{
  display:none;
}
```

This way you can save some JS overhead and also capture all problems in one go. (you may need to add `!important` if you don't want to put this at the end of your CSS / depending on the specificity of your CSS.